# Javascript variable reference and/or copy

Tags: javascript

i have e video that i am scrolling with my mousewheel.
Everything is working fine but i would like to check if the user is still scrolling and if it is not so after 10 seconds i would like the video/scrollposition to set-back to zero.

The set-back is working but it is not happing after the "Interval". It is jumping back immediately.

This is my code so far:

```
const action = document.querySelector(".action");
const video = action.querySelector("video");

//Scroll Magic scenes
const controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
let scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  duration: 200000, //64000
  triggerElement: action,
  triggerHook: 0
})
  .addIndicators()
  .setPin(action)
  .addTo(controller);

//Scroll Magic video animation
let accelAmount = 0.1;
let scrollpos = 0;
let currentTime = video.currentTime;
let lastcurrentTime;
let delay = 0;

scene.on("update", e => {
  scrollpos = e.scrollPos / 3000; //the higher the number, the slower
  });

//Move
  setInterval(() => {
    delay += (scrollpos - delay) * accelAmount;
    video.currentTime = delay;
    console.log(video.currentTime + " reading");
    lastcurrentTime = video.currentTime;
  }, 33.3);

//check if is still scrolling after x seconds
setInterval(checkTime, 10000); 

//funktion to execute the check
function checkTime() {
    console.log("waiting for new reading");
    console.log(video.currentTime + " newreading");
    currentTime = video.currentTime;
    if (currentTime === lastcurrentTime) {
      //is not scrolling -- go to start
      //video.currentTime = 0;
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen to the `scroll` event listener. With a *debounce-like* function you can start a timeout that will run whenever the use stops scrolling.

The example below uses the aformentioned technique and shows a message whenever the user stops scrolling for 1 second.

```js
function scrollTracker(delay, callback) {
  let timeout = null;

  return function(...args) {
    if (timeout !== null) {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = null;
    }

    timeout = setTimeout(callback, delay, ...args)
  };
}

const tracker = scrollTracker(1000, () => {
  console.log('User stopped scrolling. Handle your video here');
});

window.addEventListener('scroll', tracker);
```

```css
#page {
  height: 20000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="page"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are updating the `lastcurrentTime` every `33.3ms` and you're calling `checkTime` every `10s`. So almost every time you call the `checkTime`, the `lastcurrentTime` will be synced with the `video.currentTime`.

I think that I would try something like this:

```js
  let setbackTimeout
  scene.on("update", e => {
    clearTimeout(setbackTimeout);
    scrollpos = e.scrollPos / 3000; //the higher the number, the slower
    setbackTimeout = setTimeout(checkTime, 10000);
  });
```

every time you get an update you clear the countdown to setback and create another that you execute 10s later.

Answer (score 0):

I think your concept is wrong. I made a little demo how to implement it. It will print the message after 4 sec "inactivity" on button.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector("button")

let myInterval = setInterval(myPrint, 4000)

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  clearInterval(myInterval)
  myInterval = setInterval(myPrint, 4000)
})

function myPrint(){
  clearInterval(myInterval)
  console.log("programming <3")
}
```

```html
<button>Click me!</button>
```

Comment: Thank you all. I used the solution of @Emiel Zuurbier that worked fantastic for me.